Запятая перед тире: "А помочь ему я не пытаюсь — за этим пусть <...>"

А помочь ему я не пытаюсь (запятая?) — за этим пусть обращается к Николаю.

Объясните пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая или нет. Спасибо.
Предложение составлено в качестве примера (читай "я не школьник, которому нужно помочь с д/з").

Выбор знака зависит от контекста,от смысловых и интонационных оттенков предложения.
Тире указывает на неожиданное присоединение.
Здесь интонационно читается пауза, подчёркивающая контраст: "Я не помогаю, а за этим пусть идёт к другому."
Запятая лишь указывает на перечисление, постановка запятой вместо тире ослабляет оттенок неожиданного присоединения.
Двоеточие подходит, если вы хотите представить вторую часть как пояснение причины или уточнение.
"Я не помогаю, потому что за это ответственен Николай."
Однако наиболее подходящим является здесь тире, т,к. между частями БСП явно делается пауза, характерная при оттенке  противопоставления,  ножиданного присоединения.

"Однако наиболее подходящим является здесь тире" - Вы имеете в виду просто тире или тире после запятой?

Нет, только тире. Тире и запятая как единый знак или каждый на своем основании здесь не подходит.

О, спасибо. Собственно об этом вопрос изначально и был :-)
